# Einen Buchstaben als Ersetzung für ein Wort verwenden - Wie nennt man das?

Tags: single-word-request

Ich habe 5 Kategorien, die längere Wörter sind. Ich will sie durch einen Buchstaben darstellen und habe dazu eine Tabelle erstellt:

```
##################### 
# Kategorie 1 # I   #
#####################
# Kategorie 2 # II  #
#####################
# Kategorie 3 # III #
#####################
```

Ich muss eine Bildunterschrift hinzufügen und würde dann schreiben

> Die ??? der einzelnen Kategorien.

Mir fehlt aber das Wort für I, II, III. Abkürzungen sind es ja nicht, sondern eher Ersetzungen.

Comment: Inwiefern ist _III_ ein Buchstabe?

Comment: Hätte auch A, B und C schreiben können. Es geht ums Prinzip ;)

Comment: Weil es ja für die Frage gaaar nicht darauf ankommt ...

Comment: Tut es das? Es geht doch grundlegend um das Ersetzen von Wörtern. Welchen Begriff nimmt man denn für III, II, IV und welchen für A, B, C? Gibt es da ehrlich einen unterschiedlichen?

Comment: Mir fällt einer ein, ja.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ebenso wie chirlu verstehe ich zwar nicht, inwiefern III ein Buchstabe ist, aber typische Begriffe dafür (zumindest in meinem Berufsfeld) wären

- Kennung
- Identifikator
- Kurzbezeichnung

Comment: *Kürzel* passt noch gut in diese Liste.

Comment: Oder "Platzhalter"

Comment: Sowie _Sigel_ bzw. _Sigle_.

Answer (score 3):

Wenn den Kategorien jeweils eine römische oder arabische Zahl zugeordnet wird, ist das schlicht eine *Nummer* und die Tabellenunterschrift könnte folgendermaßen lauten:

> Nummern der einzelnen Kategorien.

Aternativ und meiner Meinung nach etwas passender, da es die Zuordnung betont:

> Nummerierung der Kategorien.

Bei der Verwendung von Einzelbuchstaben spricht man eher von *Bezeichnern* oder – wie von Skrijiban vorgeschlagen – *Kurzbezeichnungen*. In naturwissenschaftlich-technischen Arbeiten wird diese Art der Zuordnung auch als *Symbol* bezeichnet, vor allem, wenn das Symbol in mathematischen Ausdrücken verwendet wird.

Bei einer Zeichenkette als Kurzbezeichnung – z. B. KA für Kategorie 1 – spricht man auch von einer *Abkürzung*.

Answer (score 2):

Man nennt es

> Nummerierung

unabhängig davon, ob es sich um Zahlen oder Buchstaben handelt.

Comment: Bei einer alphabetisch aufsteigend geordneten Liste (a, b, c,...) stimme ich zu. Im Allgemeinen nicht.

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde noch 'Ziffern' vorschlagen, obwohl Ziffern für die Stellen einer Zahl stehen, und III schon 3 Ziffern hat, so gesehen, aber solange es nicht über 9 hinausgeht hielte ich das für zulässig.

Zur Liste von Skrijban würde ich die weiter genannten 'Nummern' noch hinzunehmen, sowie

- Kodierung
- Codes
- Schlüssel
- Bezeichner
- Kürzel

(teils auch in Kommentaren schon geäußert).